# Concatenate one column's text with another

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA beginner.

I attached a picture below to illustrate my question.

[image: excel screenshot]

I would like to have the player names in the first column be concatenated through to all of the outcomes that I've listed in each of the columns (B through D), i.e.:Tramon Williams punts 1 yards, Tramon Williams left end for 1 yards, Tramon WIlliams left tackle for 1 yards, etc. and then down to Tramon Williams punts 2 yards, Tramon Williams left end for 2 yards, etc.

When that's completed, moving onward to Frostee Rucker (the next player).

There are 2900 entries in column A to be concatenated across certain outcomes.

Comment: you have not fully described what you are trying to do. you said that you would like to concatenate string data from column A and each of the other columns. no mention made of where you are putting the string data after it is concatenated. .... also you have not asked any question ....is there any reason why you are repeating the same data in all those columns and now you want to make it more repetitive?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I should have clarified--I'd be putting the information into a new tab in the workbook. Its not the same data, rather slightly different outcomes (1 yard left tackle, 2 yard left tackle, etc.) Being able to have a player name concatenated with all of the potential outcomes will allow me to drop a new set of data in (say for a new week of games to analyze the play by play which contains things like concatenated strings) and be able to automate analyzing at a broader level weekly, if that makes sense.

Comment: you could use cell formula. insert formula in empty cell on row 2  `=$A2 & " " & B2`. copy the cell an paste across as many columns as you have data and as many rows as data  .... just experiment with it ... you can copy the formula cell into a small range at first, and see how it looks

Comment: Hi Jstola---wouldnt I have to then repeat that task 2900 or so times or am I mistaken?

Comment: which column is the first free column ?

Comment: I would be putting into a blank column into a new tab in the work book----but I'd need to have the name in the first column (Starting in A2) have gone through every single one of the actions listed in the next columns. I thought simply concatenating it would mean I'd have to do it for every single player I have there (2900 or so)?

Comment: go to sheet2 ... click cell B2 ... type `=`  (just the equal sign ... it tells excel that you are entering a formula) ........... go to sheet1 and click A2 .... return to sheet2  .... you should see `=Sheet1!A2` in cell  .... type `[ & " " & ]`(do not type brackets) ..... got to sheet1 and click C2 and press enter  .... now sheet2 B2 should show `=Sheet1!A2 & " " & Sheet1!B2`  .... add $ like this `=Sheet1!$A2 & " " & Sheet1!B2`    ............... now select sheet2 B2 and press ctrl-C (copy) ...... select a bunch of cells (example: sheet2 B3:E10) and press ctrl-V (paste)

Comment: the way you have formatted the data in your database makes it very difficult to do any math on the data. you are repeating the column name and row name in the table data, which is redundant. each cell already has a player name and type of rush attached to it

Comment: try this: insert column at B, and put in date (week number) .... column A is still names ..... the stats columns are shifted over by one now .... remove all text from stat data cells (leave number only)  ..... add next weeks stats under this weeks (names, date, stats)  the whole sheet has only one header row. ..... now you can filter the data. ... do pivot tables ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recon there's much to be improved in your excel table (e.g. `20` gives the same info as `punts 20 yards` when written into the column `punts`)...

However: you could take one step at a time, so let's stick with the solution you wanted and how you can achieve it with rather simple means (loops, mostly)

Try this example and play around with it

```
Option Explicit

Sub PopulateArray()

    Dim blndimensioned As Boolean
    blndimensioned = False

    ' array for your concatenated strings
    Dim arrFoobar() As String

    ' array with the fieldnames to concatenate
    Dim arrColumns() As Variant
    arrColumns = Array("Punts", "Rush Left End", "Rush Left Tackle", "Rush Left Guard")

    Dim fldname

    ' adjust this to your actual sheet
    With GetRecordset(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange)

        ' loop the rows
        While Not .EOF

            ' loop the columnvalues
            For Each fldname In arrColumns

                If blndimensioned = True Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrFoobar(0 To UBound(arrFoobar) + 1)
                Else
                    ReDim Preserve arrFoobar(0 To 0)
                    blndimensioned = True
                End If

                ' dimension the array, populate it with concatenated values
                arrFoobar(UBound(arrFoobar)) = ![Playtype MasterList] & " " & .Fields(fldname).Value

            Next fldname

            .MoveNext
        Wend


    End With

End Sub

Function GetRecordset(rng As Range) As Object

    'Recordset ohne Connection:
    'https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/

    Dim xlXML As Object
    Dim rst As Object

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

    rst.Open xlXML

    Set GetRecordset = rst

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much Martin--- Sorry, I think I'm still doing something wrong here: I updated the GetRecordset field within this workbook to the worksheet I'm trying to pull the values from, but I'm still getting an Run Time error saying that there is a type mismatch as a result of the Array values (arrColumns = Array("Punts", "Rush Left End", "Rush Left Tackle", "Rush Left Guard", "Rush Middle", "Rush Right Guard", "Rush Right Tackle", "Rush Right End") highlighted?

Comment: My mistake. Changed to `Dim arrColumns() As Variant`. Should work now.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried to run and got "Run Time Error 3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal", and the debugger highlighted the dimension the array line (arrFoobar(UBound)....etc does the Sheet name need to be in quotation marks within the brackets?

Comment: missing blank in `![Playtype MasterList]`.